# Minimal API with Azure Application Settings

Tags: azure-web-app-service, application-settings, minimal-apis

I cannot get my application settings or connections from Azure Web App update my .net 6.0 minimal api. I've tried using environment variables but that only tells me there's a string value. I've also tried using other methods such as the normal way of reading a config which doesn't work for Azure.

In my Appsettings.json:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {     
        "Context": "",     
        "Redis": ""   
    },   
    "Logging": {     
        "LogLevel": {       
            "Default": "Information",       
            "Microsoft": "Warning",       
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"     
            }  
    },   
    "Where": "Still AppSettings..." 
}
```

In my appsettings.development.json:

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
     "Context": "...",
     "Redis": "..."
   },
   "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
   },
   "Where": "Local",
}
```

On one of my api endpoints I have the following code:

```
public static string Index(IConfiguration configuration) => configuration["Where"] ?? "Failed";
```

When I debug this, I get "Local". If I deploy this to Azure I get "Still AppSettings..."...

I've also tried various things in my program.cs

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.InkML;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Twilio.Services;
using Twilio.Web.Endpoints;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddLogging();
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options => { options.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").GetValue<string>("InstrumentationKey"); });
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "TEST API v1",
        Description = "TEST API documentation",
        Contact = new OpenApiContact() { Name = "CCS Dev", Email = "testing..." }
    });
});
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
var appSettingValue = config["Where"];
var connection = config.GetConnectionString("Context");
builder.Services.AddScoped(c => new TestContext(builder.Configuration["Context"]));
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => { options.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis"); });
var appSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");

builder.Services.AddScoped(c => new TestService(
    c.GetRequiredService<TestContext>(),
    c.GetRequiredService<ILogger<TestService>>()
));
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{}

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.RegisterHomeAPI();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.Run();
```

In my Home.cs:

```
namespace Endpoints
{
    public static class HomeApi
    {
        public static void RegisterHomeAPI(this WebApplication app)
        {
            app.MapGet("/", Index);
            app.MapGet("/Home", Index);
            app.MapGet("/Home/Inxed", Index);
            app.MapPost("/", Index);
            app.MapPost("/Home", Index);
            app.MapPost("/Home/Inxed", Index);
        }
        // GET: Home
        public static string Index(IConfiguration configuration) => configuration["Where"] ?? "Failed";
    }
}
```

In Azure:
[image]

I've checked several blogs that allowed me the opportunity to discover ways that this doesn't work for my instance...
https://build5nines.com/azure-web-app-connection-strings/
https://medium.com/awesome-azure/azure-reading-application-settings-in-azure-functions-asp-net-core-1dea56cf67cf
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-read-the-app-settings-from-azure-in-net-core/
I've also looked at Microsoft and various stackoverflow questions but nothing seems to work for me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core6x

Comment: _" I've tried using environment variables but that only tells me there's a string value"_ - note that corresponding environment variables should look like `ConnectionStrings__Context` and `ConnectionStrings__Redis`.

Answer (score 1):

Iam able to read the App settings from Azure.

I have created a `.Net Core 6` Application with `Minimal API`.

[image]

We need to add the configuration file for multiple environments.First get the environment and add it to the ConfigurationBuilder.

Change the `ConfigurationBuilder`  as below

```cs
var config = $"appsettings.{app.Environment}.json";
IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .AddJsonFile(config, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

My `Program.cs` file after integrating your swagger.

```cs
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddLogging();
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options => { options.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").GetValue<string>("InstrumentationKey"); });
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "TEST API v1",
        Description = "TEST API documentation",
        Contact = new OpenApiContact() { Name = "CCS Dev", Email = "testing..." }
    });
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

var config = $"appsettings.{app.Environment}.json";
IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .AddJsonFile(config, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var appSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");


if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

var summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast");


app.MapGet("/appsettings", () =>
{
    var appsett = app.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Where");
    return $"Settings from  {appsett}!";
})
    .WithName("AppSettings");
app.Run();


internal record WeatherForecast(DateTime Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary)
{
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

***Local Output when there is value in `appsettings.Development.json`:***

[image]

***Local Output when there is no value in `appsettings.Development.json`:***

[image]

***Deployed App Output:***

[image]